# How to realize a distributed queue with unreliable participants?

Tags: data-structures, distributed-systems, peer-to-peer

I want to build an application that relies on a distributed queue with participants in a decentralized (peer-to-peer) network. The participants cannot be relied on to correctly follow a protocol.

I found the distributed queue dual-bus algorithm, but I think it only works with reliable participants.

Is there an algorithm/protocol that can be used in this scenario?